# Reading ungenerated properties from User-class springSecurityService in a Grails GSP

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm writing an update user-data form in Grails. It must show an old user data in the fields before update. This is a part of this form:

```
<g:form class="form-signin" controller="VisitorSpace">
    <label for="login" class="sr-only">Login</label>
    <g:textField id="login" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="Login"
        value="${applicationContext.springSecurityService.principal.username}" required="" autofocus=""/>
    <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">Your name</label>
    <g:textField id="firstName" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Your name"
        value="${applicationContext.springSecurityService.principal.firstName}" required="" type="text"/>
...
</g:form>
```

This is a part of my domain User-class:

```
class Person {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
    boolean isAdminCafee = false
    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        firstName blank: false
        lastName blank: false
        password blank: false
        email blank: false, unique: true
    }
    ...
}
```

Generated username-property of the domain class is getting correctly, but while I trying request ungenerated firstName-property I get an error:

```
URI:/restorator/visitorSpace/editPrivateDataClass:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyExceptionMessage:
No such property: firstName for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've solved this problem via rendering gsp with parameters.
Render-action of gsp-controller:

```
def editPrivateData(){
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        render (view:'editPrivateData.gsp', model: [user: user])
    }
```

Using in gsp-form:

```
<g:textField id="firstName" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Your name" var = "user" value="${user.firstName}" required="" type="text"/>
```